# Parsing the XML to print a string with formatting attributes per word

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I have an XML which contains a field of the type:

```
<mytext><![CDATA[ My name is <color value="FF0000">Bill</color>. ]]></mytext>
```

Since I'm new to E4X methods, I wonder if there is a simple methodology (using E4X methods) in order to print the inner text: "My name is Bill." in a text area and having the word "Bill" colored i.e. red.

The generalized situation is, if i can print the inner text and use XML tags to specify formatting attributes of the text per word.

Do E4X supports this type of parsing, or do I have to program my own "little" parser for this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's normalize the html content (I added a `<content>` tag to make it valid):

```
var mytext:XML = XML("<mytext><![CDATA[<content>My name is <color value="FF0000">Bill</color>.</content>]]></mytext>");
```

Next step is to parse the given XML:

```
var roughXML:XML = XML(mytext.text().toString());
```

Then you have to substitute your custom tags with standard tags:

```
var output:XML = XML("<span/>");
for each(var tag:XML in roughXML.children())
{
    if (tag.name() == "color")
    {       
        var fontTag:XML = XML("<font/>");
        fontTag.@color = tag.@value.toString();
        fontTag.appendChild(tag.text());
        output.appendChild(fontTag);
    }
    //you can add here any rule for substitution that you need
    else
    {
        output.appendChild(tag);
    }
}
```

And finally, you can use an `s:RicheEditableText` to display your text

```
var textFlow:TextFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(output.toXMLString(), TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
myRichEditableText.textFlow = textFlow;
```

Comment: Wow!! I think (i'm still studying it..) this is what i need! Just a little addition: after the **if clause** with tag.name(), after the var fontTag... i think it must be entered fontTag.appendChild(tag.text()) ? right?

Comment: Just one more comment, because i do not know yet (i'm going to study it) the TextConverter class: When i change the 2nd argument importToFlow() method to **TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT** i just get the text without color, and when i put the constant you provide, i only get the out-of-color-tag-text: "This is". Is there a problem with how i specify the color?

Comment: Once again, my mistake, I should have written TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT. About the color, I think you should add a # before the color if there isn't.

Comment: Thanks!! So, the philosophy is that i specify my tags, and try to convert into HTML tags...cool!

Comment: And here are the tags you may use: http://help.adobe.com/fr_FR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/conversion/TextConverter.html#TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT